# python types in bencode.py

Tags: python, types, bittorrent

Sorry for my simple question.

I try to use bencode.py from deluge or bittorrent 5.0.8.
But I find a string

```
from types import StringType, IntType, LongType, DictType, ListType, TupleType
```

but I do not know where this types is.
What I need to install for use this types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [`types`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) is a standard Python module included in the Python distribution.  You don't need to install anything in addition to Python itself.

As far as I remember, it has been around forever (which means at least since Python 1.5).

Comment: thanks a lot, for test I use Python 3.2, when I install Python 2.7 the problem checked

Answer (score 3):

Its part of the standard library. It should work right away.

Comment: thanks a lot, for test I use Python 3.2, when I install Python 2.7 the problem checked